# How can I write a unit test for angularJs Factory

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, factory

**EDIT:** (add test code)

Hi I have this factory which haven't any function definition.. I don't know how can I write an unit test for it (I see a lot of examples but still can't find a way to do this if you have any suggestions or help I will be very thankful) 
My factory :

```
MyApp.factory('params', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    // supported languages
    var params = {
        layout: {
            pageAutoScrollOnLoad: 2000
            pageSidebarClosed: false, 
            pageBodySolid: false, 

        },
        layoutImgPath: Metronic.getAssetsPath() + 'app/img/',
        layoutCssPath: Metronic.getAssetsPath() + 'app/css/'
    };
    $rootScope.params = params;
    return params;
}]);
```

As in the answer proposed by @MoLow I try to do exactly the same.

```
describe('params', function () {
var params;

beforeEach(module('params'));
beforeEach(inject(function (_params_) {
    params = _params_;
}));

it('Should ', function () {
    expect(params).to.be.a('Object');
 });

});
```

. But I have this error :

> TypeError: undefined is not an object

That's means that params is undefined.I don't know why .I need help to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
describe('params', function () {
    var params;

    beforeEach(module('params'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_params_) {
        params = _params_;
    }));

    it('Should ', function () {
        expect(params).to.be.a('Object');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer .. I try it But my test FAILED and I get this error : `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Metronic`

Comment: How can I avoid this error ?When I comment this 2 lines (which contain Metronic)to see the result I get this error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'expect(params).to.be')

Answer (score 1):

Remember to include all your dependencies (Metronic) when you load the tests, in your karma.conf.js file if you're using karma.

Comment: thank you @pansay for your answer but I can't find any js file for Metronic dependencies is this the only possible solutin for my problem? I can't use spyOn in this case ?